# Python: PyVisa with USB connection - > wait_for_srq() or wait_on_event?

Tags: python, usb, visa

I'm trying to controlling to a USB instrument (Keithley 2450) using pyVisa but I get an error. I'm following the simple example on the [pyVisa website](http://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/master/example.html)

I have a problem after I send a "service request"

```
keithley.wait_for_srq()
```

and it throws an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'USBInstrument' object has no attribute 'wait_for_srq'
```

It seems with that's command I can't communicate via USB. What can I to do to remote communicate with my instruments via USB interface ?
Hopefully, you can me help. I'm new in Python and SCPI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried with my Pyvisa just now, it has the same problem as well. I'm currently using Pyvisa version `1.8`.

I think it is due to that when you open the device, you used the `usb` interface`instead of the`gpib` interface.

If you go to the source of [`wait_for_srq`](http://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/pyvisa/resources/gpib.html#GPIBInstrument.wait_for_srq) in pyvisa, you can see that it is only belong to the `GPIBInstrument`.

Unlike [`wait_on_event`](http://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/1.5-docs/_modules/pyvisa/ctwrapper/functions.html#wait_on_event), it is directly wrapped around the NI-VISA C libraries, which means this method is available for all types of instruments (`GPIBInstrument`, `USBInstrument`).

So probably you can use the function `wait_for_srq` with the `event_type` set to be `Service Request` (i didn't try from my side).

And to be noted that `SRQ`(Service Request) is defined by IEEE 488 standard and it is one of the few number of lines that are dedicated to signalling and control on the GPIB. Which means `SRQ` is exclusively available in GPIB interace but not USB.